# Separate two Firefox windows as if they were different apps

Tags: unity, 18.04, firefox, configuration

I'm trying to start two Firefox windows and have Ubuntu (18.04) treat it as two different apps.

The reason I'm trying to do that is that I have two Firefox profiles. One has my company's proxy and allows me to browse freely but doesn't allow access to our client's webapps. My second profile contains this client's proxy and only gives access to the client's remote webapps.

So far I have made a `.desktop` file that opens Firefox with the client profile (the first one is set as default). When I use the `.desktop` file it opens Firefox with the client's profile as a new Firefox window. I'd like to know if it was possible to make it as if it was a different app in order to have two distinct icons in the dock ?
EDIT: here are the contents of my .desktop:

> [Desktop Entry]
>       Version=1.0
>       Type=Application
>       Terminal=false
>       Exec=firefox -P ClientProfile
>       Name=Firefox ClientP
>       Comment=Firefox with Client proxy
>       Icon=/opt/firefox_ico/ico.jpeg

Comment: in the .desktop file you made try changing the startupWMclass to something else (add a 1 at the end for example), maybe that will work.

Comment: It didn't work, sadly. I added my desktop file contents in my original post, in case I messed up something. I added StartupWMClass=TestingCustomFF but no such luck.

Comment: A hack could maybe be to remove the startupwmclass from the firefox .desktop file, I think this will cause all firefox instances to use a separate icon in the dock, but I can't test it now

Comment: Hi, happy New Year! Sorry for the delayed response, I was on vacation away from my computer. Anyway, I didn't find a StartupWMClass in the default firefox.desktop (/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop).